# Order table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

For example I have this table

```
Student 1 | Math    |F
Student 2 | Math    |F
Student 2 | English |F
Student 2 | Science |F
Student 2 | History |P
Student 3 | Math    |F
Student 3 | English |F
Student 3 | Science |F
Student 3 | Biology |F
```

What I want to do is order the table so that the Student with the highest number of 'F' get to be shown on top first like below and so on and so forth.

```
Student 3 | Math    |F
Student 3 | Science |F
Student 3 | English |F
Student 3 | Biology |F
Student 2 | Math    |F
Student 2 | English |F
Student 2 | Science |F
Student 1 | Math    |F
Student 2 | History |P
```

How do you do this in SQL?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the SQL documentation for `order by`? Do you have specific requirements on how all of teh students with an `F` grade are ordered?

Comment: I have tried counting for the 'Marks" column but it does not base its count on the Student row.

Comment: Student 2 has highest number of F (together with Student 3). Still you are showing Student 2's P record after Student 1. Is this a mistake or do you want to show all F first and have the ranking only inside these records? And does it matter whether to show Student 3 or Student 2 first? If so: by what rule do you want them ordered?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, ok my bad. Ill edit it and make student 3 having four 'F", thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No, the sample data was good. Now there is no tie and you think you don't have to explain the rule for ties, but that's not true. There can be ties, so we need a rule. And then I wanted to know whether it is on purpose that you split the Student 2 rows and have Student 1 inbetween. You haven't answered that either.

Comment: Yes, I wanted all 'F' to be shown first before the 'P', how do we deal with the ties?

Comment: *You* should know that. Either you don't care which of the students with the same count to show first or you take their Ps into account or you order by name then, ... You name the rule.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `CASE` and windowed `COUNT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN mark='F' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
   ,COUNT(CASE WHEN mark='F' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY student_name) DESC
   ,student_name DESC;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e9320071cd047c6e565edc2a16721ae1)**

Answer (score 0):

Just use :

```
SELECT Student, Lesson, Mark 
  FROM Marks
 ORDER BY Mark, regexp_replace(Student,'\D') desc;
```

by `regexp_replace(Student,'\D')` you get number part only.